# What is the meaning of '?' in the Racket docs?

Tags: racket

[Example](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._number%7E3f%29%29):

```
(number? v) → boolean?

  v : any/c
```

I understand the '?' behind 'number' but the second '?', behind 'boolean' irritates me. Does it mean that it *maybe* returns a boolean, and maybe not?

**Edit for clarity**

I come from Python, to me this reads as: `is_number::function returns is_boolean::function` and not `is_number::function returns bool::bool`.

**Solution**

As Jérôme explained, it reads as:

```
is_number(v) returns b where is_boolean(b) == True
```

**Update 2022**

[Section 2 in the Racket reference](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/notation.html) explains the formal syntax used throughout the documentation. The `?` gets explained in [section 2.3](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/notation.html#%28part._.Notation_for_.Function_.Documentation%29).

Quote (I added the links):

> ```
> (char->integer char) → exact-integer?
> char : char?
> ```
>
> Each [metavariable](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/notation.html#%28tech._metavariable%29) is described with a [contract](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contracts.html#%28tech._contract%29). (...) The metavariable `char` has the contract `char?`. This contract specifies that any argument `char` that answers true to the `char?` [predicate](https://docs.racket-lang.org/racket-glossary/index.html#%28part._.Predicate%29) is valid. The documented function may or may not actually check this property, but the contract signals the intent of the implementer.

Comment: seems to be a is_number equiv. ?

Comment: yes, that is how i understand the first '?' too, but what is the use of the second?

Comment: I just mean `is_*` in general - not the number-specific one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boolean?` is a predicate. It's a function that has (by convention) a question mark at the end to show it can be used to check for the type of a value and return a boolean, like so:

```
> (boolean? #f)
#t
> (boolean? "hello")
#f
```

By default Racket is dynamically typed, so in order to show type information in the documentation, **predicates are used as a kind of type annotation**.

So basically, `(number? v) → boolean?` means "The function `number?` returns a value which, when passed to the predicate `boolean?`, returns true".

It becomes useful when you have more complex predicates:

```
(pick-random-stuff bag?) → (listof (or/c toy? food? paperclip? aligator?))
```

This function returns a list containing any amount of those different objects in any order.

#### Notes

It is considered a good practice to always name your predicates with a `?` at the end.

You might have noticed though that in my examples, `listof` and `or/c` don't have question marks. It's because they are not predicates themselves, but functions that build predicates.

In most lisp languages, like Scheme, Racket, Clojure, or Common Lisp, a lot of symbols that have specific meanings in other languages are just valid identifiers. `?`, `=`, `-`, `->`, `+` are all allowed inside variable and function names.

Comment: So, this means that `(number? ...)` returns a predicate function instead of a raw boolean?

Comment: @Nils Nope, it returns a raw boolean. The function `number?` itself is a predicate. The `?` is part of the name, not some kind of specific syntax.

Comment: i understand this, but why is the '?' behind the boolean? It makes sense in your code example, but why behind a return value?

Comment: `boolean?` is a function that checks if a value is a boolean.

Comment: The function will not actually be called. It's used as a type annotation. It means: "this function must return a value which, when passed to `boolean?`, returns true."

Comment: Ah! Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `(number? v) → boolean!` would me much more clear in my opinion.

Comment: It's useful because it allows to link to the corresponding predicate's documentation. When you click on `boolean?`, you are redirected to the description of `boolean?`. When defining a lot of custom types, like `person?`, `dinosaur?`, `home?`, it's easier to use predicates. You can also have more complex predicates: `(listof (or/c number? boolean?))`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, so it is much more powerful than eg. `isinstance` in Python